# npm fails out of the network

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack-dev-server

I have a trouble with npm, when I'm connected in my net it works nicely, but then I disconnected the computer, it stop working. When I run any command npm related, it fails giving me this error. Does anyone knows what's going on in there?

I have a Mackbook pro with Capitan OS

```
webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack.config.js --content-base ./app/ --watch --hot --inline --progress

70% 4/4 build modulesevents.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack.config.js --content-base ./app/ --watch --hot --inline --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on ubuntu? When you go offline it switches apache off too so localhost vanishes, you need to be connected for it to run.

Comment: I have a Mackbook pro with Capitan OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the key to find the solution:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
```

I went to my /etc/hosts file and I notice that localhost was not there anymore.

Add this line:

```
localhost     127.0.0.1
```

Everything is fine now.